# How to retrieve list from SQL alphabetically except one item?

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table with a column for Occupations in a table in SQL. Along with a few occupations, I also have an item for 'others'. I will display these in a dropdownlist and  on selecting 'others' I will show a text box.

Ex: Business
    Student
    Employee
    Others

I want to retrieve the list in Ascending Order, but when I do that using `ORDER BY ASC` 'Others' will come somewhere in between. I want it to be at the end of the list being returned.

Like Business
     Employee
     Student
     Other

Please suggest a solution to keep the Others at the end of list while retrieving.
(Note: The list is dynamic and will be changing , so I cannot hardcode)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN <YourValue> = 'Others' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS PrimaryOrder 
    FROM <YourTable>
) AS SubQuery01
ORDER BY PrimaryOrder, YourOrderByCriteria
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
select occupations from mytable where occupations != 'Others' order by 1 ASC
union
select occupations from mytable where occupations == 'Others';
```

but it's overkill, you can add others by hand

Answer (score 0):

I have tried out a solution and is working for me..

```
SELECT O.NAME FROM OCCUPATIONTABLE O
 ORDER BY CASE
        WHEN O.NAME = 'Others' 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END ASC
        ,O.NAME ASC
```